# Разбить строку на массив слов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка в формате xml

```
<Name>Chelik</Name>
```

Как разбить строку на массив слов?

Нужно получить `Chelik` и использовать как имя обьекта в программе, причем важно, чтобы на это влиял тэг `<Name>`, т.к. программа должна понимать, что это имя именно этого обьекта, а не какого-либо другого.

Comment: @michael_best  речь не о js

Answer (score 3):

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<Name>(.+?)</Name>", Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<Name>Chelik</Name>");
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // выводит Chelik
```

если у нас в тексте несколько таких тегов, то как-то так:

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<Name>(.+?)</Name>", Pattern.DOTALL);

private static List<String> getNameValues(final String str) {
    final List<String> nameValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        nameValues.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return nameValues;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли

Comment: для разборка XML лучше не применять регулярки, а воспользоваться специализированными парсерами